# Run gitlab on subdomain in local network?

Tags: gitlab, subdomain, raspberry-pi4, local-network

I installed gitlab on a raspberry pi 4 in my local network and will use it only locally. When I configure in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` the `external_url 'http://rpi4.local'` (and execute `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` afterwards) it works. I can even configure a different port here.

But the configuration `external_url 'http://gitlab.rpi4.local'` does not work. Do I need to configure something else, like my `/etc/hosts` file ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the name valid in DNS through some mechanism. There are multiple ways depending on your needs and your options for DNS.

1. As you mentioned, you can add the name to your `/etc/hosts` file. This should be done both on the GitLab server and on any workstation you wish to have access to GitLab (assuming Linux-based machines. The process differs for Mac or Windows).
2. Use a valid DNS name and add it to your DNS. Use a name such as `gitlab.<a-domain-you-own>` and add it to DNS. Many domain registrars offer DNS for free or you could use a dynamic DNS service if your Raspi has a dynamic internal address. The advantage of using this method is you won't have to modify any `/etc/hosts` files and all workstations will know how to access your GitLab instances without any changes.